# How to select a source work book work sheet base on a cell value?

Tags: excel, vba, select

How to select a worksheet from a source workbook base on the text on a cell in active workbook.

Here is my code:

```
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(wsActive.Range("B1"))
Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

I open the source workbook base on the cell B1 in active workbook, but how to select a worksheet base on a cell in active workbook?

For example, if I put "Sheet4" in cell B2 in active workbook, wsSource will select the Sheet4 from the source workbook.

Comment: `Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(wsActive.Range("B2").Value) `

Comment: Note: Try to get in the habit of using `Worksheets` instead of using `Sheets` since `Sheets` can also contain chart objects. It's not just a shortcut that does the same thing. It may seem trivial now, but it may be important in your work some day.